# how to implement popup window without any actions performed in android?

Tags: android

I want to show up pop up window after an activity has been launched. It is just like after a few seconds delay pop up should come. How can I implement that?Any ideas or examples?? If so I will be helpful ..Thanks in advance.

Comment: Research Alert dialogs

Comment: Use a Handler + postDelayed http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: google alert dialogs and once you learnt how to show one you can use handler/thread etc to delay the pop up time .

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do so.
If you have a list of Activities where you want to show the POP-up, you can uses two ways:

1. Create a service which actively checks for the foreground [Top most activities] in the stack and if the activity on which you want to show the pop-up, just send the broadcast to show the pop-up.
2. Create a Class which extends a Asynctask class, which waits for Xsecs in doinbackground and shows a pop-up over onpostexecute, Just call the execute of the Asynctask class while oncreate ends if you want to show only one time.

Asynctask class will be the best to use in such scenario. By this you can re-use this asynctask class every where in the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){ @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
           //call your toast here.
            //TIME_OUT is no of milliseconds you want to wait before Toast is popped.
        } },TIME_OUT);
```

Hope this helps.